# how to store float numbers in mongodb php

Tags: php, mongodb, floating-point

I have a well-known issue about floats in php, but still can not get good resolution for it.

I'd like to work with user's balance, that can be very little, actually. 
For example. Balance is 0.00015 and i want to substract 0.0001 from it. Of couse, i've got 0.00005, but it displays as 5.0E-5 . 
How can i save this value in mongo db, and then work with it correctly?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "it displays"? Where does the value "display" like that? When you `echo` it in PHP before inserting the value into the DB? In the MongoDB shell after you inserted it? When you pull it out of the DB with PHP and then `echo` it? Somewhere else?

Comment: when echo it before insert - shows 5.0E-5, it shell it is 0.00004999999999999449

Comment: aaah, you need [the floating point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Comment: Those two are actually fine, the problem is that PHP is showing it in E notation while console it showing it as it is needed right?

Comment: actually yes. i need to show actual 0.0005 to user interface...

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert, but this looks like a case for the `number_format` function.